# An Extension Method to deal with Null property values in Razor?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4

I would like to create an extension method which can test a strongly type property value for null, take a replacement value ie "N/A" if null, otherwise run the original code line. The explicit version is :

```
            @(Model.Birthdate == null ? "N/A" : Model.Birthdate.Value.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"))
```

Rather than applying this test to all values in the view I was wondering whether there was a more eloguent approach using an extension method, somewhat like:

```
@(Model.Birthdate.Value.TestForNull("N/A"))..... I am trying to write my idea out and am not sure it is possible with the date formatting as well! Perhaps one has to do it line by line.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a simple Extension method to use as part of your Helpers.

```cs
public static class DateTimeExtensions
{
    public static string ToStringOr(this DateTime? dateTime, string value)
    {
        return dateTime.HasValue ? dateTime.ToString() : value;
    }
}

// Your model
public class Person
{
    public DateTime? Dob { get; set; }
}
```

Then use in your view:

```cs
@Model.Dob.ToStringOr("N/A");
```

Answer (score 1):

I would instead resolve this logic in the model.
You can wrap the conditional in a string property that returns either N/A or the date string.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that the way you expect. Because the 'original' line might access a null pointer, it leaves you with the ternary operator. If you really want an extension (I advise against it, as it will pollute all objects), you can do:

```
public static TOutput FallbackTo<TInput, TOuput>(this TInput input, Func<TInput, TOutput> execute, TOutput fallback) 
    where TInput : class
{
    return input!= null ? execute(input) : fallback;
}

public static TOutput FallbackTo<TInput, TOuput>(this Nullable<TInput> input, Func<TInput, TOutput> execute, TOutput fallback) 
{
    return input.HasValue != null ? execute(input.Value) : fallback;
}
```

Alternatively, a more broad and streamlined version:

```
public static TOutput FallbackTo<TInput, TOutput>(this TInput input, Func<TInput, TOutput> execute, TOutput fallback)
{
    try 
    {
        return execute(input);
    }
    catch(ArgumentNullException) 
    {
        return fallback;
    }
}
```

In your case you could then do:

```
@(Model.Birthdate.FallbackTo(d => d.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"), "N/A"))
```